# NSURL max length?

Tags: ios, nsurl

I need to pass text string up to 20Kb (one NSURLQueryItem value) from one iOS app to another using schemes. I was able to pass not such long URL between the apps.

What is max NSURL length supported? Does it depend on iOS version? Is there any better approach to send text long string?

Comment: I suggest using `UIPasteBoard` or some other method to pass a file to another app. Passing large file data on the URL isn't a good idea.

Comment: If you control both the apps you can make them part of the same app group and store a file where they can both access it

Comment: both comments can be accepted as answers. thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

NSURL can easily handle 20Kb.

The implementation limitation is around 2Gb (`INT_MAX`) for the URL string. The limitations you'll run into first with large URLs are memory and time. You'll run out of memory for the allocations at some point (For 32-bit executables, the limitation is a little over 1.1GB when your process runs out of address space; for 64-bit executables, the limitation depends on your system's available VM swap space). Creating very large URLs will take a **lot** of time to create and parse.

Comment: any proof link?

Comment: You can look at the source for CFURL (NSURL objects are really CFURLs unless you subclass NSURL) at https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/CoreFoundation/URL.subproj/CFURL.c

Last time I looked, I was still listed as responsible for the maintaining that code (but I'm retired now LOL).

Answer (score -1):

Did you get a 414 (request too long) on your request? There is no formal limit, but systems have ad hoc limits which may be as low as 8k.

You should use a POST instead of putting all the data in the URL.

Comment: the question is about interaction between iOS apps (not sure you've understood the question correctly)

Comment: I apologize. I looked at the docs for URL Schemes and it doesn't mention a length limit anywhere. I also read Ray Wenderlich's tutorial and he doesn't mention a limit either.  I did find a note about a limit of 50 schemes per device which appears to be undocumented.